# Copying to tmp table on disk mysql takes way too long

Tags: mysql, performance, join, inner-join

I need to query an InnoDB table (100 millon rows) but it's impossible beause it lock the table and stops my application (must keep running on query execution)

**QUERY:**

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ptown_billing.historial_cobros.FECHA, 
    "Cobro ok." as ESTADO,
    ptown_common.carriers.CARRIER as CARRIER,
    ptown_common.precios.DESCRIPCION as DESCRIPCION,
    SUM(ptown_common.precios.PRECIO_SIN_IVA) AS PRECIO_CLIENTE,        
    SUM(ptown_common.precios.COMISION) AS COMISION,  
    count(*) as CANTIDAD,      
    ptown_common.productos.producto as PRODUCTO,
    ptown_common.origen.origen AS ORIGEN,
    ptown_common.keywords.KEYWORD,
    ptown_common.shortcode.SHORTCODE,
    ptown_common.partners.PARTNER,
    ptown_common.empresas.EMPRESA  
FROM ptown_billing.historial_cobros
    INNER JOIN ptown_billing.cdr ON cdr.ID_CDR = historial_cobros.ID_CDR AND 
        cdr.DB_MODULO='ptown_suscripcion' 
    INNER JOIN ptown_suscripcion.transacciones  ON 
        ptown_suscripcion.transacciones.id_transaccion = ptown_billing.cdr.ID_TRANSACCION 
    INNER JOIN ptown_common.solicitudes  ON 
        ptown_common.solicitudes.ID_SOLICITUD = ptown_suscripcion.transacciones.ID_SOLICITUD  
    INNER JOIN ptown_common.keywords_partners ON 
        ptown_common.keywords_partners.ID = ptown_common.solicitudes.ID_KWPT 
    INNER JOIN ptown_common.partners ON 
        ptown_common.partners.ID_PARTNER = ptown_common.keywords_partners.ID_PARTNER  
    INNER JOIN ptown_common.empresas ON 
        ptown_common.empresas.ID_EMPRESA = ptown_common.keywords_partners.ID_EMPRESA  
    INNER JOIN ptown_common.keywords  ON 
        ptown_common.keywords.ID_KEYWORD = ptown_common.solicitudes.ID_KEYWORD           
    INNER JOIN ptown_common.carriers ON ptown_common.carriers.ID_CARRIER = ptown_billing.cdr.ID_CARRIER
    INNER JOIN ptown_common.productos_config ON 
        ptown_common.productos_config.id_configuracion = ptown_suscripcion.transacciones.id_configuracion 
    INNER JOIN ptown_common.shortcode  ON 
        ptown_common.shortcode.ID_SHORTCODE = ptown_common.productos_config.ID_SHORTCODE  
    INNER JOIN ptown_common.origen ON ptown_common.productos_config.id_origen = ptown_common.origen.id_origen        
    INNER JOIN ptown_common.productos ON ptown_common.productos.id_producto = ptown_common.productos_config.id_producto
    INNER JOIN ptown_common.precios ON ptown_billing.cdr.ID_PRECIO = ptown_common.precios.ID_PRECIO 
WHERE ptown_billing.historial_cobros.fecha = '2013-11-26' AND 
    ptown_billing.historial_cobros.respuesta = 000 
GROUP by FECHA,DESCRIPCION,CARRIER,PRODUCTO,ORIGEN,KEYWORD,SHORTCODE,PARTNER,EMPRESA
```

Any suggest? I tried settting tmp_table_size = 51200 but got no results.

Comment: What sort of query do you execute? what type of Engine do you use?

Comment: @JungsuHeo im using an innodb table. It's a SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE from a table with 150m rows and 15 joins, with groups by and counts. It's a data-warehouse process i need to run everynight.

Comment: Thank you for reply. would you give us more information in detail? something like this. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16172/trying-to-optimize-query-for-performance-mysql. then other people can help you. thanks.

Comment: Read this and see if it helps: dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-locking.html

Comment: however OLAP query is optimized with other's help, maybe it takes long time. (I guess, I didn't see your query) so, what about replicating your data and execute query on slave db?

Comment: @JungsuHeo I just edited and uploaded the query.

Comment: Thanks for responses. I was thinking about replication but I need to resolve this with some urgency so i'm wondering if it's a problem with my server configuration

Comment: @FedericoCarrizo thanks. but output of EXPLAIN is missing. would you please... and I think subject of question is not proper. something  like "InnoDB multiple INNER Join optimization help" would be better, then many people come and help you. "copying tmp table" is not attractive. I hope you soon clear this problem. thanks.

Comment: @JungsuHeo Thanks for your time. I'm almost sure the problem it's not caused by joins. The query works on two huge tables (50m and 100m rows) while I receive many other requests (inserts and updates) so if it's locked my applications stops works. Thanks.

Comment: @FedericoCarrizo I think what @InoSHeo meant by `output of EXPLAIN is missing` was to attach results of EXPLAIN query to your question, not just add it at beginning of query :)

Answer (score 0):

You are joining together 14 tables!

Based on my experience, in 99% of cases like this, it turns out that adding an index fixes things.

Look at all the `ON table1.field1 = table2.field2`, and make sure ***table1*** has index on ***field1*** and ***table2*** has index on ***field2***.